# Streaming live video from iOS using HTTP

Tags: ios, video-streaming, http-streaming

I have read about HTTP Live Streaming from Apple. So far I understand that it was created for streaming video to iOS devices. But is it possible to use this approach to stream **from** iOS device while recording on camera? If so can you give me a clue or tell how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yes. But I would not recommend it. HLS is a pull based protocol. Good for delivering to clients, but bad for ingesting. Would need to run a web server on the device, and package the media into a transport stream. Its a lot of effort that is easier to handle on the server.

Comment: Could you recommend me better solution?

Comment: For live ingest, I would recommend RTMP, RTSP, WebRTC or something custom.